# What C++ refactorings do you use in practice?

Tags: c++, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I'm going to create the comparison table of existing automated C++ refactoring tools as well as explore an ability of creation of such tool, free and open-source.

My question is: what refactorings do you really use in your everyday work? There are obvious things like renaming variable/class/method, but is there something specific for C++, like dealing with templates, STL, copy constructors, initializers, etc., etc?

I'm interested in building of realistic picture of all that little problems that C++ developer is facing each day in his coding and that could be automated at least in theory. I'm talking to my colleagues but that's probably not enough.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good luck in creating a decent C++ parser to make such a tool work.

Comment: When I was developing in C++ I didn't use much refactoring support from the IDE. There simply was none that I found really useful. My advice would be to learn your design patterns, read Meyer's Effective C++, then 101 Coding Standards. Learn to do it more or less right from the start.

Comment: @Daniel: Refactoring is the main tool of a developer, whatever the program. In keeping with the KISS principle, you don't dive into patterns just for the sake of it, but only use them piecemeal for just what you need at the moment... for you're no oracle.

Comment: @Jim: CLang offers a full C++ parser library, indeed of the main goal is to provide easy rewriting or source-source translation.

Comment: A C++ Parser is hard, and the preprocessor contributes to that mess. C++ name resolution is harder. C++ flow analysis is probably equally hard. You still have to be able to regenerate the C++ source text after a refactoring. You'll find doing all this pretty difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said there are obvious things:

- renaming is one
- altering a function signature is another (especially since a function is almost necessarily duplicated: declaration in the header and implementation in the source)
- renaming / moving a file (update of include directives)

Note that though it's basic, it's rarely well dealt with. My primary complaint being that comments are generally not updated (I am so not speaking about doxygen auto-generated useless clutter). So if I was describing the use of the class within a header, or the justification of using this class in another source file, the comment is now obsolete because by renaming the class no one will now know what it refers to...

There are however much more interesting cases:

- When changing a function signature, you need to update all the call sites, the developer will need help for localizing them
- With inheritance, the ability to act on all classes of a hierarchy: changing a function signature (once again) or adding/removing a virtual override.
- With template: the Concept proposal having been dropped, it would be good if you could synthetise the requirements on the type passed (methods / inner types necessary) so that when altering those requirements (by modifying the template definition) one gets notified of the list of classes that are in use by this template and no longer conform to it (and shall be updated). Note that in case it's just renaming the type / method, you might want to automatically propagate the change, as long as it doesn't break anything else.

Good luck...

Comment: Just renaming is hard.  Imagine renaming I to J... where there is a J in a scope between I's declaration and I's use ("shadowing").  This includes intervening scopes with multiple inheritance; J might not even appear explicitly in the actual intervening scope declaration. Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty clear from the answers that few C++ programmers have ever seen a real refactoring tool.  Yes, they are quite rare and highly specific to the IDE you use.  That's inevitable, there is otherwise no good way to find out what source code files contribute code to the final executable.  The preprocessor makes it extra challenging, you need to know the macro values.  A source code parser is required but not enough.

Visual Assist for VS is one I know of.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in Martin Fowler's [Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Refactoring-Improving-Design-Existing-Technology/dp/0201485672/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1290079359&sr=8-1) and [Refactoring to Patterns](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Refactoring-Patterns-Addison-Wesley-Signature-Kerievsky/dp/0321213351/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1290079359&sr=8-2) by Joshua Kerievsky.  These in turn reference the GoF [Design Patterns](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Design-patterns-elements-reusable-object-oriented/dp/0201633612/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1290079413&sr=8-3) book so get that too.

If you can beyond the basic Rename Feature and Extract Function then you might be onto a winner.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a C++ design pattern I came up with yesterday: *Ditch inheritance in favor of policies*.

Comment: The first time I read that I came up with *Ditch inheritance in favor of **politics**.*

Comment: Didn't Alexandrescu came up with it before you or did you just realized how good policies where ?

Answer (score 1):

One refactoring that I wish was supported is actually *inject* method.  More-or-less the opposite of *extract* method.

Because perhaps I see that I can then rearrange the resulting code to better clarity or effect; but I am not aware that there is tool support for this at present.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i use http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/RefactorCPP/ with this tool i do renaming variable/class/method, changing function body,initializers

Comment: Those are very basic things though...